# Setting up where_clause to select counties one at a time from feature class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, where-clause

I need to select a single county at the time from the "counties" feature class. I am using a make feature layer with a where clause.

How do I set up the where_clause to select each of the counties in the row? The field list to be used by the update cursor is "COUNTY". In this list are all the 64 counties names. Here is what I have so far:

```
# where clause
COname = ??????
where_clause = "COUNTY = '" + COname + "'"
print where_clause
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (CountyPath, "county_lyr", where_clause)
```

Comment: If you are planning to copy the selected feature out into its own feature class then I recommend using the Select tool or jumping to Split By Attribute instead.

Comment: If you are planning to use an update cursor on your counties feature class it seems odd to have MakeFeatureLayer involved.

Comment: You say "In this list are all the 64 counties names." but your code snippet currently makes no use of a Python list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you want to get a list of what's there first and then iterate each one.. take for example:

```
AllCounties = [] # blank list
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(CountyPath,'COUNTY') as SCur:
    for SRow in SCur: # go through each feature one by one
        if SRow[0] not in AllCounties: # check it's not already in the list
            AllCounties.append(SRow[0])

for ThisCounty in AllCounties:
    where_clause = "COUNTY = '" + ThisCounty + "'"
    #... do the rest of what you need to do here
```

On the surface all looks good, but you have to consider case sensitivity. File geodatabases and shapefiles are case sensitive so I would suggest something like this:

```
AllCounties = [] # blank list
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(CountyPath,'COUNTY') as SCur:
    for SRow in SCur: # go through each feature one by one
        if SRow[0].upper() not in AllCounties: # check it's not already in the list
            AllCounties.append(SRow[0].upper())

for ThisCounty in AllCounties:
    where_clause = "upper(COUNTY) = '" + ThisCounty + "'"
    #... do the rest of what you need to do here
```

To do all your comparisons in upper case. Both SQL and python have `upper` methods but they are used differently; in python you would uppercase `StringVar` by typing `StringVar.upper()` but in SQL you would perform an uppercase comparison of field `StringField` by typing `upper(StringField)`. In both languages there is the option of `upper` and `lower` but try to stick to the same case, it would be frustrating to find the uppercase matching string in a list of lowercase strings.

Comment: What do you mean "if SRow[0].upper() not in AllCounties"?  It is returning zero counties.

Comment: It will on the earlier iterations, the reason for doing it this way is to ensure a county doesn't appear in the list more than once.