# Calculating total numbers of wells that fall into each county of table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, table, intersect

Directions: 
For each county calculate the total numbers of wells that fall into that county, and update the county table with the total count. This is the code I have so far.

Problems:

1. The counties selected only returns 1, so I know there is an error somewhere.
2. Not sure if things are in order and I am not sure if the intersect of counties and wells and the total count even happened.

---

```
import arcpy

#variables
CountyPath = "C:\\PythonProgramming\\Lesson 5\\Lesson5_Data\\COUNTIES.shp"
WellsPath = "C:\\PythonProgramming\\Lesson 5\\Lesson5_Data\\Wells.shp"
fieldList = "COUNTY"

# select single counties
AllCounties = [] # blank list
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(CountyPath,'COUNTY') as cursor:
    for row in cursor: # go through each feature one by one
        if row[0].upper() not in AllCounties: # check it's not already in the list
            AllCounties.append(row[0].upper())

for COname in AllCounties:
    where_clause = "upper(COUNTY) = '" + COname + "'"
    print where_clause

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (CountyPath, "county_lyr", where_clause)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (WellsPath, "wells_lyr")

#use update cursor to calculate the total numbers of wells that fall into that county
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(CountyPath, fieldList, where_clause) as cursor:
 for row in cursor:
     row[0] = row[0].upper()
     cursor.updateRow(row)


#select statement 
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("wells_lyr", "INTERSECT", "county_lyr", "", "NEW_SELECTION")
```

I am new to this.

Comment: Your SelectLayerByLocation needs to be earlier, and your update cursor is only performing an upper case replacement of your counties.

Comment: Have you considered using a spatial join? Much simpler! You could pretty much condense your script down to just a few lines (spatial join and then join field).

Comment: I agree with @Luke. This is a textbook case for a point in polygon spatial join.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being an online GIS tutor.  Since your question involves ArcPy code it is worth reviewing these [tips for writing code snippets](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from where [your previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289199/setting-up-where-clause-to-select-counties-one-at-a-time-from-feature-class-usin/289205#289205) left off:

```
for COname in AllCounties:
    where_clause = "upper(COUNTY) = '" + COname + "'"
    print where_clause

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (CountyPath, "county_lyr", where_clause) # Just one county
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (WellsPath, "wells_lyr")                 # all wells

    # reduce all wells to the ones inside the county
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("wells_lyr", "INTERSECT", "county_lyr", "", "NEW_SELECTION")
    # find the count of wells selected
    CountOfWells = int( arcpy.GetCount_management("wells_lyr").getOutput(0) )
    # print a message identifying the county and the count of wells
    arcpy.AddMessage('County {} has {} wells'.format(COname,CountOfWells))

    # don't use update cursor to calculate the total numbers of wells that fall into that county
    # arcpy.GetCount_management works just fine. Use this to update your count in this county field
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("wells_lyr", "CountThisCounty") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0] = CountOfWells
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

The process works like this:

1. Create a layer that contains just one county.
2. Select from the wells the ones that intersect that county.
3. [Get the count](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) of wells in that county (I think that's what you're after).
4. Using an [update cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) on the wells set the values and store.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to work through this right now and see what I get.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: All is good so far, the list of counties print line by line.  However,  I get this message:       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PythonProgramming/Lesson 5/AYoung_Homework5.py", line 30, in <module>
    for row in cursor:
RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.     (I need to update the COUNTY table with the column called NoWells... not sure if this is the information I need for that parameter?

Comment: with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("wells_lyr", "CountThisCounty") as cursor:
    for row in cursor: #this is the line I am getting the error
        row[0] = CountOfWells
        cursor.updateRow(row)

Comment: Substitute the *real* field name from your wells feature class for "CountThisCounty"; the  field in the wells wasn't mentioned in your script so I just made that up as a place marker.